# Process Builder - invoking another process builder

Tags: process-builder, businessprocess

I have 2 process builders.  Both are tied to the Case object.  I want to process builder #1 to invoke process builder #2.  process builder #2 is active.  However when I search for the name of process builder #2, it says there are no results.  Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can only invoke another process when it's created with the setting "The process starts when" is set to "It's invoked by another process". Processes that are configured to launch when a record changes or when a Platform Event is posted cannot be launched by other processes.

[image]

You may also consider factoring common functionality for the two Processes into an autolaunched Flow, which both processes can launch.